# Apply grok for logfiles

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, grok

I ma new to Grok and logstash.

```
2016/02/18 - 03:52:08|service|Info|some message in different format
2016/02/18 - 03:52:08|service|Info|Time to process "tweet_name" is 40.1081357 second(s)
```

I will have messages like above format.  What I want is, I want to extract the following things,

1. datetime
2. service
3. loglevel
4. message
5. tweetname
6. timetoprocess

Item 5 and 6 will be available only if the message starts with `Time to process`

I have written a grok but i am not sure how to extract item 5 and 6. Because #5 and #6 will be available only in certain line of log message.

```
filter {grok { match => { "message" => "(?<datetime>(([0-9]+)\/*)+ - ([0-9]+:*)+)\|%{WORD:service}\|%{WORD:loglevel}\|%{GREEDYDATA:message}" }}}
```

how can I get item #5 and #6 and apply the grok?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using two grok stanzas.  First, pull off the common stuff (your #1-#3).  Put the remaining stuff back into [message] using the 'overwrite' parameter to grok{}.  That's pretty much what you have in the grok you provided, but it'll be more clear if you use built-in patterns like %{YEAR}

Then, use a second grok stanza with match patterns to handle the other types of values left over.  Something like this:

```
grok {
    match => { "message" => "Time to process \"%{DATA:tweet_name}\" is %{NUMBER:tweet_sec} second\(s\)" }
}
```

If you have other messages for which you'd like to make fields, add more patterns to the grok stanza.  It will process them in order until it finds a match and then exit out.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add new grok for different message.
            It will process them sequentially,after matching correct pattern it exit out.